Licence that allows charging for distribution
I want to ask if a. a licence with the following requirements exists and b. if such a licence would be open source (OSI and/or SFS):

The licence should allow the user a similar level of freedom as a non-copyleft-licence (MIT, Apache), so no copyleft. They should be able to redistribute the source, make changes to it, keep those changes to themselves, compile it, distribute it, ...
Each user should pay a specific amount, if they make more than $X in revenue per year. (Like some popular game engines do)

Example 1: I publish a library under said licence, each program that uses that library has to pay the fee. The programs can be open source or not, I do not care about that. If the program is forked, because it is open source, the fork also has to pay the fee, since it uses my library (if it does not, then it would not have to pay for the library, of course)
Example 2: I publish a library under said licence, another library B uses my library. Users of that library B have to pay for my library if B directly exposes the functionality of my library. If it just uses my library under the hood, users of library do not have to pay for my library. (That one would be hard to get legally get right, I think)
Obviously, this would not be GPL-compatible, but I do not care about that. But that could be achieved by dual-licensing it under the (A)GPL since the GPL is toxic for most business environments anyway.
Most open source projects would be fine without paying for my library at all, since they (most of the times) do not make any revenue, so the licence would be equivalent to an Apache/MIT-style licence.
Reason: I want to monetize my work without relying on some practices I do consider morally wrong (advertisment, ...). This seems to me a fair restriction on the use of my work.

A requirement of "pay X amount if you make (more) money" is not free. It's a limitation on the "use as you wish for any purpose" and as by that such license would not qualify as a free or an open source license. It is called freedom 0 in this article).
Additionally, it also would somewhat fail the island test: assume I'm in a secluded community with this software without access to the outside world - but I make a fortune with it within that community. How would I be able to follow the license requirements to pay (e.g. you)?
Practically another problem is: how do you attribute currency conversions and to what rate? How do you account for non-monetary transactions? All this fine-print of legalese would be required and would immediately require a definition of the legal system to use - which fortunately none of the open source licenses requires. What if your bank details change? Am I supposed to find out or will you notify me? Can you maliciously often change your bank details so that I cannot pay to make my license void and sue me? What happens if the stated recipient does not exist anymore?

Thanks for the answer. How does my requirement differ from the requirement given in the GPL that allows demanding pay for the software? As I understand, the GPL allows putting a price tag on my work.
Well, I do not think the island test would be a big progblem, I could include a clause stating that if the customer is unable to pay because he is physically unable to do, he does not have to, which would also migitate some of the other problems you state.
Thanks for the input!

The difference is that should you choose to buy a copy of GPL software from the original author, you get freedom along with the product: you may then give copies to anyone you want, at no further cost.

Under GPL I can sell you the software - I'm not required to give anything for free. However, if I sell the software, then the license requires that I must give you the source code for free if you wish so. And the license grant allows you to do with the software as you wish - including distributing it for free to anyone you wish

@MadHatter Thanks! That clarifies that. Has there been precedence where some tried to add a requirement like the one that I stated and it got denied by the FSF/OSI?

It doesn't need to be.  GPLv3 s7 says that if anyone tries to add "further restrictions", those restrictions may simply be removed.  A requirement such as you propose would constitute such a restriction, and - with no further input from the FSF or anyone else - would be invalid on its face.

@MadHatter Sorry, phrased that a little bit mistakable. I meant has there been precendent where someone tried to add a requirement like "Every user of this software has to pay $X" to his licence, not the GPL. From my point of view, there seems little difference between a copyleft clause and a "pay per use"-clause. In fact, in most practical instances, a "pay per use"-clause would give the use more freedom that a copyleft clause, which also restricts what the user can do with this software

@planetmaker Thanks for your input, I just want to point out that some open source licences do have a forum clause, like e.g. the QPL, which defaults to the law of Norway: "This license is governed by the Laws of Norway. Disputes shall be settled by Oslo City Court." (last sentence of the Q Public Licence)

@0968FC1F126E85E51FBF0B43D0B02D, your "payment to original author" clause is a "phone home provision" and is listed as a common reason for rejecting licenses by OSI: https://opensource.org/licenses/common-reasons-for-rejection-of-licenses

@BartvanIngenSchenau I understand that, but couldn't that be migitating by providing a  provision like "if the user is unable to reach me, he does not have to pay"? But I do not want to escalate this discussion any further, I think I got my answer. Thanks for all of those who contributed so far!

@0968FC1F126E85E51FBF0B43D0B02D and how would one determine "was not able to contact"? That's not a workable legal definition IMHO - and something which is a serious legal danger for anything not open source. Copyright expires only 95 years after the confirmed death of the author (yay :/).
